# How are US Health Saving Account (HSA) taxed in Canada for a Canadian citizen, not a US citizen?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, hsa

The HSA in question is founded while legally working in the US and being a US tax resident. However, I'm thinking of coming back to Canada.

Are they just considered as a normal account? Therefore, the gains are taxed each year, but the contribution will never be taxed by Canada.

Or are they considered as like an RRSP (like traditional IRA and traditional 401k are) and therefore the gains and contributions are taxed when we use them?

Or is it something else?

Also, after 65 years old, it is possible to use them without penalty, therefore by the US-Canada treaty, a flat 15% tax will apply in the US. Can this tax be deduced for Canadian tax?

I live in California, therefore I am paying taxes right now on my contribution to my HSA. This tax cannot be deduced for Canadian tax right now since I'm not a Canadian tax resident right now. However, in the case they are considered as like an RRSP, can I deduce those taxes I already paid while removing the money?